# Did Ron's Sneakoscope light up because of Wormtail?

Tags: harry-potter

In the beginning of the 3rd book, Ron sent Harry a gift on his birthday from Egypt. The gift also had a letter which reads:

> “Harry — this is a Pocket Sneakoscope. **If there’s someone untrustworthy around, it’s supposed to light up and spin.** Bill says it’s rubbish sold for wizard tourists and isn’t reliable, because **it kept lighting up at dinner last night.** But he didn’t realize Fred and George had put beetles in his soup.”

Is it possible that Ron analyzed the situation wrong and Pocket Sneakoscope actually light up because Pettigrew was secretly present there?

Comment: Pettigrew had been hiding out with the Weasley family for ten years; http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Peter_Pettigrew

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Almost certainly. We see it again a few scenes later **lighting up room with only Harry, Ron, Hermione, Crookshanks and Scabbers (Pettigrew) present.**

> ***He, Ron and Hermione went to the library next day, and returned to the empty common room*** laden with books which might help prepare a defence for Buckbeak. The three of them sat in front of the roaring fire, slowly turning the pages of dusty volumes about famous cases of marauding beasts, speaking occasionally when they ran across something relevant.

Then

> *Crookshanks’s fur suddenly stood on end. A shrill, tinny whistling was filling the room. **The Pocket Sneakoscope had become dislodged from Uncle Vernon’s old socks and was whirling and gleaming on the floor.**
>
>   ‘I forgot about that!’ Harry said, bending down and picking up the Sneakoscope. ‘I never wear those socks if I can help it …’
>
>   The Sneakoscope whirled and whistled in his palm. Crookshanks was hissing and spitting at it.
>
>   ‘You’d better take that cat out of here, Hermione,’ said Ron furiously; he was sitting on Harry’s bed nursing his toe. ‘Can’t you shut that thing up?’ he added to Harry, as Hermione strode out of the room, Crookshanks’s yellow eyes still fixed maliciously on Ron.*

Ron, of course assumes that it's down to Crookshanks rather than Pettigrew.

Answer (score -3):

I find it difficult to believe. Keep in mind, even if Peter was in danger of getting discovered and murdered by Sirius black he would not dare attacking Harry around the Headmaster and at Hogwarts. Sneakoscopes show immediate danger their owner might be facing or possible untrustworthy things.

Comment: I think you're mistaken. Pettigrew *is* the untrustworthy thing that's the common factor when it goes off.